# How do I resolve this ReferenceError: "tStart" is not defined. (line 55, file "Code")?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create calendar events from data in google sheets and each time I run the code I get ReferenceError: "tStart" is not defined. (line 55, file "Code").  Please see the code below.  I'd be grateful for any assistance.

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName( 
      "admin@someaddress.co.uk" )[0];
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[8];  // First column
    var tstart = row[9]; // Second column
    var tstop = row[10];
    Logger.log(tstop);
    var desc = row[1];       
    var loc = row[4];
    //var cmmail = row[6];
    //var leamail = row[7];
    cal.createEvent(title, new Date(tStart), new Date(tStop),{description:desc,location:loc});
  }
}
```

I was expecting this to pick up the active spreadsheet and identify the dates in column J and add these to as new events to calendar.

Answer (score 3):

JS is case sensitive, so "tstart" and "tStart" are two different variables.

You should either try changing tstart to tStart in your initial declaration, or vice-versa.

Comment: Thought I had adopted camel casing, thanks for spotting this error.  It is now throwing up a different error entirely. Missing ) after argument list. (line 19, file "Code")
    cal.createEvent(title, new Date(tStart), new Date(tStop),{description:desc,location:loc});
  }
}

Comment: Could you please share your updated code? I've just tried to run the script and everything works properly here.